Records not yet detected (Last checked just now)
i want to add custom domain to my web app deployed on firebase but its showing this error from last 24 hours.
Records not yet detected (Last checked just now)
It can take up to 24 hours for changes to propagate. You can close this dialog for now and check again later.
Setup mode
i have added correct records on Hostinger but still its showing the same text after 24 hours.

The issue i was facing was that my domain was suspended by Radix and i checked by adding my domain on this link https://abuse.radix.website/unsuspension  and filed unsuspension request.
